# Inputting data from a form to a database trouble

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, insert-into

I've created a form where I input data and it is then saved into the database. My database is created using PHPMyAdmin and the Primary keys are auto-incremented (so this has been ruled out). I can input Data but only once after that any data being added will not appear. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for the data input:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert_post'])){
//getting text from the form fields
$product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
$product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
$product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
$product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
$product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
$product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];

//image from table field
$product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
$product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];

move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");

$insert_product = "INSERT INTO 'products' 
(product_cat,product_brand,product_title,product_price,product_desc,product_image,product_keywords) VALUES ('$product_cat','$product_brand',' $product_title','$product_price','$product_desc',' $product_image',' $product_keywords')";

$insert_pro = mysqli_query($con, $insert_product);

if($insert_pro){
 echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted')</script>";
 echo "<script>window.open('insert_product.php','_self'</script>";

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a minimal example, c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @RalfStubner I have edited the question :D

Comment: i find it hard to believe that this `"INSERT INTO 'products'` did not throw a `mysqli()` error